# How can I create a secure file download in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, php, javascript

I need you help. I'm currently trying to develop a secure file download in PHP and WordPress. I've already done the upload and deletion part but now I need to handle the download - somehow.

The file get's saved inside a `deny from all` folder in the `wp-uploads` directory.

Currently I have a table with an entry for each file and one download button at the top. When I now select some rows and click the download button, I'm doing an AJAX request to my backend:

```
$("#storage-download-btn").click(function() {
  let data = {
    action: "download_from_storage",
    selected_storage_files: getSelectedStorageFiles()
  };

  $.post(ajax_url, data, function() {}).success(function() {}).fail(function(response) {});
});
```

During this request I've planned to do some checks:

1. Does the file/files exists?
2. Is the request valid?
3. Is the encrypted filename saved in the DB?

If everything is true, I need to download the file somehow. I saw a plugin using `query_vars` by sending a result link to the browser which get's loaded and this downloads the file. Is this is a good idea? Or is there something better?

I've tried setting query vars but I'm not sure if this is secure enough and good because I only want to allow file download via my AJAX request and the checks there.

Comment: Sounds like you're re-inventing the wheel here. The Easy Digital Downloads plugin does this better than anything custom you're likely to come up with.

Comment: @vancoder I don't want any plugin here. Thats not maintainable and unsecure.

Comment: It's a lot more secure than rolling your own.

Comment: @vancoder but it's not working as I need it.